# Trying to display cost a single tree in my program

Tags: java

Could you tell me whats wrong? Basically I am trying to display the users input that is stored in the variable "oneTree" and post on the screen so that when I write it, it displays how many the price for one tree.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class greenfields
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 String choice;
 int forDelivery;
 int numTrees;
 int treeHeight;
 double oneTree;
 double treeCost;
 double deliveryCost;
 double totalCharges;
 double totalTreeCost;



 System.out.println("How many trees do you want to purchase?");
 numTrees = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter the height of the trees you want to purchase.");
 treeHeight= keyboard.nextInt();


 System.out.println("Would you like the trees be delivered?  Enter 1 for Yes, Enter 0 for No.");
  forDelivery= keyboard.nextInt();
  if(forDelivery==1)



    if(numTrees <5 )
   deliveryCost = 10.00 * numTrees;

   else if (numTrees >=5)
   forDelivery=50;

if(treeHeight <= 5);
    treeCost =numTrees * 69.50;
if (treeHeight <= 8);
    treeCost =numTrees * 99.00;
if (treeHeight >=9);
    treeCost= numTrees * 199.50;
 if(treeHeight <3)
 treeCost= numTrees * 39.00;

  if(treeHeight < 3)
    oneTree = 39.00;
  if(treeHeight == 3 || treeHeight == 4 ||treeHeight== 5)
    oneTree=  69.50;
  if (treeHeight == 6  || treeHeight== 7 || treeHeight == 8)
   oneTree = 99.00;
  if ( treeHeight > 8)
   oneTree =199.50;

   totalTreeCost = numTrees * treeCost;

   System.out.println(numTrees + " Trees at "+ " each:" +treeCost+ "\n" + totalTreeCost);

    }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong?

Comment: Any errors? Expected output vs Actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove the **;** after your if condition, your if condition is currently doing nothing

```
 if (treeHeight <= 5) ;
    treeCost = numTrees * 69.50;
    if (treeHeight <= 8) ;
    treeCost = numTrees * 99.00;
    if (treeHeight >= 9) ;
    treeCost = numTrees * 199.50;
    if (treeHeight < 3)
        treeCost = numTrees * 39.00;
```

Secondly, you should use **else if**, because if treeHeight <=5 also then also treeHeight <= 8, without else if, **you are applying both conditions to treeCost**.

So the correct code should be:

```
 if (treeHeight <= 5)
        treeCost = numTrees * 69.50;
    else if (treeHeight <= 8)
        treeCost = numTrees * 99.00;
    else if (treeHeight >= 9)
        treeCost = numTrees * 199.50;
    else if (treeHeight < 3)
        treeCost = numTrees * 39.00;
```

Comment: `System.out.println(numTrees + " Trees at "+ " each:" +treeCost+ "\n" + totalTreeCost);`....   I feel like this is also out of order.

Comment: hmm, a sample output is - 5 Trees at  each:347.5
1737.5, Looks good to me:)

Comment: It really should be 5 Trees at 347.5 each: 1737.5

Comment: @Alexander oh, you mean the grammar? I only thought about if the data are printed out correctly.

Comment: @Alexander fair enough

Comment: @MannyDebarge Just add treeCost = 0;

Comment: Oh yeah and im not finished formatting. Thank you guys!

Comment: oh nvm figured it out